# Rank of matrices that are the products of square and non-square matrices

Tags: matrices

Can someone give me a proof for the following statement?

$B$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, then the rank
of $AB$ is the same as the rank of $A$ for every $m\times n$ matrix
$A$. Is the converse true?

Thank you all

Comment: rank of a matrix is the dimension of the range. What is the rank of $B$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan its $n$ for here right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $B$ is invertible then $B$ is nonsingular so $rank(B)=n$. Now we know that the rank of $CD$ is less than or equal to the minimun between $rank(C)$ and $rank(C)$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties). Can you continue from here?

The converse is not true. What happen if $rank(A)<rank(B)<n$.

Comment: How do you prove that rank of $CD$ is equal to the minimum between $rank(C)$ and $rank(D)$?

Comment: It is a standard result: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties.

Comment: Alright, then converse may not be true if we set B as $n \times n$ singular matrix which has rank that is higher than A but less than $n$?

Comment: I edited my answer with a hint for the second question.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was just the information that I needed :)